# Travel to Ireland (Dublin) with UK visa (Indian citizen)

Tags: visas, uk, ireland

I am an Indian citizen who applied for a UK tourist visa (short stay, multi-entry) to be issued from India. I wish to travel to Dublin. Would I be entitled to enter Ireland? Note: I will first enter the UK.

I appreciate your response if anyone had experienced a similar situation.

Comment: Do you have the BIVS endorsement on your visa? Refer to this Irish page or the relevant UK documentation http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/British+Irish+Visa+Scheme

Answer (score 0):

Border Control Checks operate on entry to Republic of Ireland and Northern Ireland with airlines and ferries and more so upon re-entry to Great Britain. 
Travel between the Irish Republic and Northern Ireland is usually hassle free but sometimes checks are made at the main line bus and train stations at Belfast and Dublin and Dundalk (ROI) and Newry (NI). Car travel between Belfast and Dublin and other routes normally tends to be hassle free unless there is security/smuggling/drugs checks. PSNI and Garda Siochona police forces cooperate on suspected national and international criminal activity.

Comment: "Border Control Checks operate on entry to Republic of Ireland and Northern Ireland with airlines and ferries and more so upon re-entry to Great Britain" The Uk doesn't do border checks when entering from Ireland by air, but when flying to Ireland, even from the UK, there are full border checks. By ferry there are spot checks.